# sendmail emails are going to spam (not on yahoo!!)

Tags: email, email-server, sendmail

I send confirmation code for users to register on my site, it's going directly to spam on hotmail and gmail, but on yahoo, it's getting to the inbox.

the hotmail spam filter sucks so much, i get so many real spam emails in my inbox and i get facebook emails in my spam, so i'm not surprised at all when i see my emails getting to hotmail junk folder, I do not care where my emails go to, on hotmail.

but yahoo and gmail have excellent spam filters, my emails are going to the yahoo inbox and gmail spam, isn't strange!

I have seen many solutions on serverfault, I'm gonna try them, but the question here is why the emails are getting to the inbox of yahoo and the spam of gmail :)

one answer on serverfault suggests that I should check my ip on [senderscore](http://www.senderscore.org), i did that, the results are:

hostname: none
Other IPs with same hostname: none
blacklists: none
Return Path Certified: none
Return Path Safe: no

would you need to see the whois lockup?

correct me if i'm wrong but i think the emails are going to spame because the hostname is none, the return path certified is none and the return path safe is no

but then, why I'm getting emails in my yahoo inbox?

**EDIT:** no, they are not spams, all the message say is this:

Hello user,
Thank you for joining website.com, one last step is required in order to activate your account

Click Here
{there's a link here}

Email : the user's email
Username : username
Activation code : 124kew

if above given is not working , please go here and activate it
http://website.com/activation.php

====================
Regards
website.com

here's my email header

```
Received: from website.com ([178.18.17.167])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id x7si1606511yba.84.2011.09.16.15.41.21
        (version=TLSv1/SSLv3 cipher=OTHER);
        Fri, 16 Sep 2011 15:41:21 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: 178.18.17.167 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of support@website.com) client-ip=178.18.17.167;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=neutral (google.com: 178.18.17.167 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of support@website.com) smtp.mail=support@website.com
Received: from website.com (localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1])
    by website.com (8.13.8/8.13.8) with ESMTP id p8GMh6dX000451
    for <me@gmail.com>; Fri, 16 Sep 2011 22:43:06 GMT
Received: (from apache@localhost)
    by website.com (8.13.8/8.13.8/Submit) id p8GMh6k0000450;
    Fri, 16 Sep 2011 22:43:06 GMT
From: support@website.com
X-Authentication-Warning: website.com: apache set sender to support@website.com using -f
To: me@gmail.com
Subject: [website.com] - Account activation email
Date: Fri, 16 Sep 2011 23:43:06 +0100
Reply-to: support@website.com
Message-ID: <cc24a7f816793b9cf16466fc7914bf76@website.com>
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.1 (phpmailer.sourceforge.net)
```

Comment: I suspect they are going to the SPAM folder because your messages look like SPAM...  Can you update your question with some actual details.  Perhaps the headers of some of the messages that got into the SPAM folder?

Comment: @Zoredache I updated the question sir

Comment: This looks like Spam: No SPF, no DKIM, no rDNS record, no personal greeting, "click here"-URL, not much text in the mail, ... My Anti-Spam would score it as Spam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the website Address from the subject line. When an email from an address that is not in their address book (even a temporary address book that is held by the site) and the subject starts with a website address it is often flagged as spam.

For example try
Account activation email for [Showpill.com]
or better yet
Account activation email for Show Pill

The other 2 things to look at would depend on if you host your website or it is hosted at a data center?

Comment: my site is hosted on a vps from 2host.com

Answer (score 1):

For help with gmail marking your messages as spam, try https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=81126